# Detect which dataset row violates the DB unique constraint during insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, ssms

I'm inserting rows into a table from other tables in the SQL Server management Studio and some records violates a unique constraint because initial data is 'dirty' and is inconsistent.

How can I find which records violate?

Comment: Just as an aside, Oracle has two ways to help. You can have it insert the failed rows in an error table for processing or you can use MERGE to INSERT only unmatched rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your only solution is to validate the constrain with a query against the source data to find the culprits. If you'd use something like SSIS you could configure it to skip over the rows that violated the constraint(s).

Comment: sad, really. the rdbms knows which failed. It just doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Work out what the key is, and try some of the following:

1) Data already exists:

select sourcekeyfield from sourcetable
where exists (select * from desttable where destkeyfield=sourcekeyfield)

2) Duplicates in source:

select sourcekeyfield, count(*) from sourcetable group by sourcekeyfield having count(*)>1

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[DataSet hell - "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values...."](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/10/03/DataSet-hell-_2D00_-_2200_Failed-to-enable-constraints.-One-or-more-rows--contain-values_2E002E002E002E002200_.aspx)

**Sanjay Sheth** states there:

> The solution lies in the GetErrors method of the DataTable class:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/cpref/html/frlrfSystemDataDataTableClassGetErrorsTopic.asp
>
> Essentially, when I see the message above, I check the HasErrors
>   property for each DataTable in the data set and then invoke the
>   GetErrors method on the tables reporting errors. The GetErrors returns
>   a collection of DataRows and you can invoke the .RowError property on
>   the each of the error-stricken rows to find out just exactly what the
>   problem is.

and adds:

> ...turn off the .EnableConstraints before the Fill. I normally enable
>   the constraints again, only after the original Fill is complete. Then,
>   you can catch the exception above and launch a error detection
>   function which does what I described above.